# How to tell if a dog's fur is matted?

Tags: dogs, grooming

I have two tamaskan dogs. One is shorthaired, and the other, Lyra, has long fur like a malamute.
I try to brush them out regularly, but she has a kind of wiry undercoat where each hair has a lot of tight waves and kind of a springy feel. Because of that the undercoat is just like one big mass of hair. It's not necessary tangled, but the hairs are so interweaved that you can't just smoothly brush through it. She has had a couple of obvious knots and lumps of fur that werent really close to the skin, mostly behind her ears and armpits, so I just cut those out. But other than that I'm kinda having trouble figuring out at what point the state of her undercoat can be considered matted.
She lies around, just like any dog. And sometimes she'll whine (not often, like maybe one or two squeaks a day) and I can't tell if she's just bored or if something hurts. She's in great health otherwise so matted fur was the only thing I could think of that could possibly be causing her discomfort.

Comment: Do you brush her hair regularly? I (as not a dog expert) would assume, that in matted fur the hairs can not fall of anymore. Like changing fur in summer/winter is not possible anymore. Then the hairs would add up, ending as a mat of hairs... My parents in law have a bernese mountain dog, kindd of curly hairs as undercoat. They need to brush nearly daily while fur is changing.